# multiple items per row with pagination

Tags: jquery

How to populate a list of items with the ability to define the count of items in each row and having pagination and also ajax calls, something like server side jquery datatables but with multiple items per row.
Is there any jquery plugin for this purpose?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: no, I want something like the product list in amazon. a list of items in thumbnail with pagination